# PDF export to local using AlivePDF with flex

Tags: apache-flex, alivepdf

I need to export charts and data tables to pdf file in flex application.

For this we can user AlivePDF but i need to export to local not server.

Can we export to local system prompting user to select the location to export?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Since FP10 the `FileReference` Class should support this via the `save()` function. The code to do this in Flash Player 10 or better is shown below:

```
var bytes:ByteArray = pdf.save(Method.LOCAL);
var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
file.save(bytes, "myPDF.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var pdfFile:PDF = new PDF();
var pdfByteArray:ByteArray =  new ByteArray ();
pdfByteArray = pdfFile.save(Method.LOCAL);
```

Comment: This only generates the bytes for the PDF. It doesn't actually prompt the user where to save it to disk as asked.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest version of AlivePDF (0.1.5 RC), you can do this:

```
var element:IBitmapDrawable; // Chart to export
var pdf:PDF = new UnicodePDF();
pdf.addPage();

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(element.width, element.height, false, 0xffffff);
try{
    bitmapData.draw(element as IBitmapDrawable);
}catch(e:*)
{
    throw new Error("bitmap draw failed");
}

var jpegencoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100);
var byteArray:ByteArray     = jpegencoder.encode(bitmapData);

pdf.addImageStream(byteArray);
var file : FileReference = new FileReference()
file.save(pdf.save(Method.LOCAL),"my.pdf");
```